# Save string with "&" character to database

Tags: php

When I have a PHP string with a "&" character, for example Dolce & Gabanna, and I save this string to the database, he only saves the Dolce part and doesn't save the part "& Gabanna". This is caused by the & character.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please show the relevant code, it probably doesn't actually have anything to do with the database.

Comment: mention datatype of coloum in whickh u r inserting this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not because of your database. It's because, you need to urlencode string with [escape](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp) or [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) functions.

**Problem:-**

> Example text in textbox:-    "Hi all & solve my problem"
>
> in the next page, you will get "Hi all"
>
> Remaining text will be missing, If you pass through get or post method

**QueryString**

```
index.php?id=2489&user=tom  //normal querystring
```

You can see, `&` is used to concatenation of two parameter. so that's why you are missing those string.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem has nothing to do with database.
It is somewhere else you're losing the rest of the string. Probably somewhere in the HTML part.

You have to follow your application logic and find the place where string got broken.
Check it before saving.
Check it before displaying in HTML.